# sinatra-authentication routes not found

Tags: authentication, routes, sinatra

I'm trying to add the sinatra-authentication gem to a Sinatra app, and while it's in there and doing part of its thing, for some reason the routes are seemingly not getting added. The code basics:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'digest/sha1'
require 'rack-flash'
require 'mongo_mapper'
require 'sinatra-authentication'

MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('127.0.0.1', 27017, :pool_size => 5, :pool_timeout => 5)
MongoMapper.database = 'cms'

module CmsMod
  class CmsApp < Sinatra::Base
    use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => 'something secret'
    use Rack::Flash

    get '/' do
      #redirect to('/list') # commented out for testing
    end

    get '/private' do
      login_required
      'Protected Page'
    end
```

And then the rest of things. The symptoms are that pointing the browser to my normal routes works fine. Going to '/private' does the redirect to '/login' properly, but I get the old "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty" message; same if I try to visit '/login' directly. I tried using 'binding.pry' to inspect things inside a get block and from what I could tell the routes aren't there. Any ideas about what could cause this would be really appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem, haven't found solution yet though.

Comment: @Masonoise - did you find the reason for this?

Comment: I ended up setting this aside, and haven't needed to come back to it yet, sadly...

Answer (score 3):

Having looked at the [library's source](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication/blob/master/lib/sinatra-authentication.rb), it's written as an extension but the examples and docs don't mention how the extension is registered. Try this:

```
module CmsMod
  class CmsApp < Sinatra::Base
    register Sinatra::SinatraAuthentication  # <= this is the missing magic line.
```

then the routes should appear. As an aside, I'd also suggest using the [encrypted_cookie](https://rubygems.org/gems/encrypted_cookie) gem.

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => 'something secret'
```

becomes:

```
use Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie, :secret => 'something secret'
```

Answer (score 3):

seems like it requires 'haml' gem as well, so if you are not using haml (like I'm using slim), you should include haml in your project for it to work, what a pain!!

Also remember to set layout in your view, because by default it will be looking for views/layout.haml

Comment: That is correct using 0.4.1 from rubygems, but 0.4.2 is on github and does not require haml.  See [this issue](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication/issues/55)